# How can I save a keras model with custom layer that have constant?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have a custom layer that has a constant, However, I can't save the model it show's the below errors. Anyone know how to save the tf.keras model with a custom layer that has tf.Variable within my custom tf.keras layer? I hope to apply a blur kernel to my Convolution neural network which trying to make the convolution layer to be shift-invariant again from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.11486)

```
# This is the layer
class MaxBlurPooling2D(Layer):

    def __init__(self, pool_size: int = 2, kernel_size: int = 3, **kwargs):
        self.pool_size = pool_size
        self.blur_kernel = None
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size

        super(MaxBlurPooling2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'pool_size': self.pool_size,
            'blur_kernel': self.blur_kernel,
            "kernel_size": self.kernel_size
        }
        base_config = super(MaxBlurPooling2D, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
        
    def build(self, input_shape):

        if self.kernel_size == 3:
            bk = tf.constant([[1, 2, 1],
                           [2, 4, 2],
                           [1, 2, 1]])
            bk = bk / tf.math.reduce_sum(bk)
        elif self.kernel_size == 5:
            bk = tf.constant([[1, 4, 6, 4, 1],
                           [4, 16, 24, 16, 4],
                           [6, 24, 36, 24, 6],
                           [4, 16, 24, 16, 4],
                           [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]])
            bk = bk / tf.math.reduce_sum(bk)
        else:
            raise ValueError
        bk = tf.cast(bk,tf.float32)
        bk = tf.repeat(bk, input_shape[3])

        bk = tf.reshape(bk, (self.kernel_size, self.kernel_size, input_shape[3], 1))
#         blur_init = tf.keras.initializers.constant(bk)

        self.blur_kernel = self.add_weight(name='blur_kernel',
                                           shape=(self.kernel_size, self.kernel_size, input_shape[3], 1),
                                           initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(bk),
                                           trainable=False)

        super(MaxBlurPooling2D, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):

        x = tf.nn.pool(x, (self.pool_size, self.pool_size),
                       strides=(1, 1), padding='SAME', pooling_type='MAX', data_format='NHWC')
        x = K.depthwise_conv2d(x, self.blur_kernel, padding='same', strides=(self.pool_size, self.pool_size))

        return x

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], int(tf.math.ceil(input_shape[1] / 2)), int(tf.math.ceil(input_shape[2] / 2)), input_shape[3]
```

```
'Not JSON Serializable:', <tf.Variable 'max_blur_pooling2d_3/blur_kernel:0' shape=(3, 3, 64, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0.0625],
         [0.0625],
         [0.0625],
         ...,
         ]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the custom layer get_config should not include the variables of ***self.add_weight***

This should solved the problem

```
class MaxBlurPooling2D(L.Layer):

    def __init__(self, pool_size: int = 2, kernel_size: int = 3, **kwargs):
        self.pool_size = pool_size
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size

        super(MaxBlurPooling2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'pool_size': self.pool_size,
            'kernel_size': self.kernel_size
            # in this config should not include the variable from add_weight but only the variables in __init__
        }
        base_config = super(MaxBlurPooling2D, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
        
    def build(self, input_shape):

        if self.kernel_size == 3:
            bk = tf.constant([[1, 2, 1],
                           [2, 4, 2],
                           [1, 2, 1]])
            bk = bk / tf.math.reduce_sum(bk)
        elif self.kernel_size == 5:
            bk = tf.constant([[1, 4, 6, 4, 1],
                           [4, 16, 24, 16, 4],
                           [6, 24, 36, 24, 6],
                           [4, 16, 24, 16, 4],
                           [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]])
            bk = bk / tf.math.reduce_sum(bk)
        else:
            raise ValueError
        bk = tf.cast(bk,tf.float32)
        bk = tf.repeat(bk, input_shape[3])

        bk = tf.reshape(bk, (self.kernel_size, self.kernel_size, input_shape[3], 1))

        self.blur_kernel = self.add_weight(name='blur_kernel',
                                           shape=(self.kernel_size, self.kernel_size, input_shape[3], 1),
                                           initializer=tf.keras.initializers.constant(bk),
                                           trainable=False)

        super(MaxBlurPooling2D, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this at the end

    def call(self, x):

        x = tf.nn.pool(x, (self.pool_size, self.pool_size),
                       strides=(1, 1), padding='SAME', pooling_type='MAX', data_format='NHWC')
        x = K.backend.depthwise_conv2d(x, self.blur_kernel, padding='same', strides=(self.pool_size, self.pool_size))

        return x

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape[0], int(tf.math.ceil(input_shape[1] / 2)), int(tf.math.ceil(input_shape[2] / 2)), input_shape[3]
```